# Change Stack Overflow login email

Tags: support, login

My Stack Overflow's login email is an email address that no longer exists. While I have changed the email address in my profile, is it possible to change the login email to the new email in my profile?

edit of an edit - I've only now just realised stack exchange logins are openID's and explanation of this rather than just slapping duplicate on it without saying anything might have been clearer...

Comment: I don't follow - your user name is "Chris Camacho". Do you mean you have two logins tied to specific email addresses that you wish to merge?

Comment: no "Chris Camacho" is my *display name* this is not used to login with

Comment: Do you still have access to the account? Or are you saying you can no longer access it?

Comment: I can access the account not the email address which no longer exists

Comment: So just add new login with email which does exist and you should be just fine.

Comment: yeah managed to get that far - now have a rogue none attached openID that I can't delete

Comment: Why can't delete? When having more than one, you should be able to remove any of them. And it is a duplicate, you ask how to change your login. Dupe closure isn't "slap".

Comment: remove != delete - having removed the id how do I delete it...?